# Pyupdater loops when a new version arrived when using nssm

Tags: windows, pyinstaller, nssm, pyupdater

My program consists of the following steps:

- check for update
- if an update exists, download it, extract and restart the program
- run update checks in a new thread every 30s
- run the main program that prints the word `YAY` every 5s

Here is the code of the update checker:

```
client = Client(ClientConfig, refresh=True)
appUpdate = client.update_check(ClientConfig.APP_NAME,
                                ClientConfig.APP_VERSION,
                                channel='stable')
if appUpdate:
    if hasattr(sys, "frozen"):
        downloaded = appUpdate.download()
        if downloaded:
            status = UpdateStatus.EXTRACTING_UPDATE_AND_RESTARTING
            print('Extracting update and restarting...')
            time.sleep(10)
            appUpdate.extract_restart()
        else:
            status = UpdateStatus.UPDATE_DOWNLOAD_FAILED
    else:
        status = UpdateStatus.UPDATE_AVAILABLE_BUT_APP_NOT_FROZEN
else:
    status = UpdateStatus.NO_AVAILABLE_UPDATES
print(UPDATE_STATUS_STR[status])
```

Furthermore, I'm trying to run the program as a Windows service using [nssm](http://nssm.cc/).

When a new version of a program is uploaded to s3, pyupdater tries to update the program but it never succeeds causing the main program to never start. However, if I don't use **nssm** it works just fine.

[Link to logs](https://pastebin.com/aLKwWSiy)